# Almacenar array de objetos gigante y evitar que el servidor se cuelgue - Node.JS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, timeout

El problema que estoy teniendo es que llega a mi **endpoint** hecho con **Express** un arreglo de objetos con más de 1000 elementos y el servidor pasados los 30 segundos, se cuelga y tira un **timeout error**. Al verificar la **Base de Datos** de todas formas puedo comprobar que a pesar de que ese error surge, se están cargando de a tandas toda la información. De hecho, si consulto unos segundos más adelante mediante otra petición me devuelve correctamente todo lo que se ha ingresado. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto? El código que implementé es el siguiente:

```
for (let obj = 0; obj < objects.length; obj++) {
  const objects_saved = await oracledb.insert(objects[obj]);
}
```

Implementé un **bucle for** por ser el más rápido. ¿Qué me recomiendan para evitar que **Express** se caiga? Pensé en fraccionar el arreglo si es más de 1000 elementos, pero estoy en la misma situación. Dicho de otra forma, pensé en dividir el arreglo en 2, 3, 4 arreglos más pequeños.

Adicional: al no recibir una respuesta de ese **await oracledb.insert** que todo se guardó de forma correcta, pasado ese tiempo ahí mismo el servidor se cae. Justamente por esa demora. Si fueran 400 objetos por ejemplo, responde con un **ok**.

El **timeout** implementado es este:

```
const server = app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}.`)
);
server.setTimeout(600000);
```

Comment: y si subis el timeout?

Comment: ahí implementé algo que encontré en la web, siendo que lo subí a 10 minutos (apropósito)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cada browser tiene un tiempo predeterminado para decidir que un request se quedó "colgado" y es mejor abortarlo (de otro modo, se mantiene utilizando recursos o puede bloquear la carga de otros assets). La regla del pulgar para XHR eran 30s, con fetch api eso ha variado pero me consta que siguen siendo 30s en firefox.

No hay manera de decirle a un browser que espere por encima de su tiempo límite, pero sí hay en cambio maneras para bajar ese límite (usando AbortController). El timeout que tú estás definiendo para Express no condiciona el comportamiento unilateral del browser.

Respecto de tu problema, me parece que es el tipo de caso de uso que más bien se maneja a nivel asíncrono, en el sentido de ejecutar la inserción en segundo plano y responder al usuario con un simple acuse de recibo.

Como ejemplo mínimo:

```
async function backgroundInsert() {
  for (let obj = 0; obj < objects.length; obj++) {
    const objects_saved = await oracledb.insert(objects[obj]);
  }
}

setTimeout(()=>backgroundInsert(),1000)

res.send('Inserción en progreso, vaya a hacerse un café y después revisa');
```

Yo sé que la idea original es proveer una confirmación de consistencia transaccional, pero el tiempo disponible no escala y en cambio el tamaño de la data sí puede aumentar infinitamente. El plan B se llama "consistencia eventual" y puede enriquecerse con alguna clase de alerta diferida (por ejemplo un correo o una notificación usando websockets).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta; entiendo el punto al cual vas y coincido con lo que señalaste. Además, al implementar esa lógica resuelve en primer plano lo que buscaba. Un cordial saludo